# Make a new struct variable when users needs it

Tags: c, struct

I'm just getting started with C, and having issues with `struct`. For instance I have:

```
struct student {
    int id;
    char name[25]
};
```

I want the user to add as many students as he needs:

```
int count = 0;
while (stop == 0){
    struct student count
    scanf("%d", count.id); 
    scanf("%s", count.name);
    scanf("%d", stop);
}
```

It looks like I've to create `struct student count` (where count is a number) and keep creating these. So, I would like to create something like `struct student 0`, then `struct student 1` and so on, so I can reference each student by it's count or number.
How would I get something like this to work?

Comment: Consider a pointer and learn about [`realloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)

Comment: Consider learning about arrays.

Comment: If you search this site for '*struct student array*' you will find this question already answered many times over.

Comment: If you know you will only ever need a fixed number of students, use an *array*. Otherwise use *pointers* and *dynamic memory allocation*. These are basic concepts of C and if you don't know about them yet, it probably means you should read some more of your text book before attempting this exercise.

Comment: Although the compiler will sort out the scope, it may be a point of reader confusing to have two completely different variables called `count`.

Comment: "Making students" actually requires an evolutionary algorithm (aka. genetical algorithm). And a keyboard is contra-productive for that ... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would like to create multiple *instances* of the struct in your first code sample for each *user* that is entered in the console, handled by the `while`-loop.

The easiest way to achieve this, is to use an array. I suggest you to first use an array with a fixed size, that means that you specify the array size in your code. This array will allow you to add as many *student instances* into it as the array size you've specified.

A simple example would be something like this:

```
// Define the student struct
struct student {
    int id;
    char name[25];
};

// ...

// Create an array with a fixed size to put the students in, and define a counter
struct student students[128];
int count = 0;

while(stop == 0){
    // Create the struct to fill
    struct student newStudent;

    // Fill the struct with the user supplied data
    scanf("%d", newStudent.id);
    scanf("%s", newStudent.name);
    scanf("%d", stop);

    // Add the struct to the array, and increase the count afterwards
    students[count++] = newStudent;
}
```

In the above example, I've added an array with a fixed size of 128, which you can change to whatever size you'd like. In the `while`-loop, an instance of a new struct is made, which is similar to before. This struct is being filled afterwards with data fed from the console. At the end of the while-loop the struct instance is added to the array of students. This will give you an array of all the students you've entered.

There is a downside to this solution however, and that's that in most cases, much more memory is consumed than is really used. This is because for the computer, it feels like 128 whole instances (or any other array size if specified) are stored in RAM, this can be quite expensive if only two instances will be really used. Also, like I said earlier, make sure to keep in mind that fixing the array size limits the amount of entries, this can also have a negative effect on your code. If you don't want to have these consequences, you may want to take a look at the solution described bellow.

You can make the size of the array dynamic, this is a little more advanced. If you'd like to achieve something like this, make sure to take a look at [memory allocation functions](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc), like [Sourav Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727169/make-a-new-struct-variable-when-users-needs-it/34728498#comment57200237_34727169) pointed out in a comment. You may also want to take a look at [the code-example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34728710/1000145) [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3628251/michael) made.

I hope this helps to solve the problem you're having. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

This will automatically allocate memory when user requests it. It starts from a dimension of 1, up to virtually infinite (actually, up to the space available in RAM).
Of course if you want, you can change the initial size of `size`, as well as the growth rate of the array.

```
// Example program
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf */
#include <stdlib.h>         /* for realloc, malloc */

// Supposing student is defined like this: 
struct student 
{ 
  int id; 
  char name[25];
};

int main()
{
  int stop = 0;
  int count = 0;
    int size = 0;

    // Using an array of students
    size = 1;
  struct student* students = malloc(size * sizeof(struct student));

  while (stop == 0)
  {
        if(count >= size)
        {
            size ++;
            students = realloc (students, size * sizeof(struct student));

            if (students == NULL)
            {
                printf ("Failed to allocate more memory.\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }   

    scanf("%d", &(students[count].id)); 
    scanf(" %24[0-9a-zA-Z ]", &(students[count].name));
    scanf("%d", &stop);
    count = count + 1;
  }

  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    printf("%d => %d  %s\n", i, students[i].id, students[i].name);
}
```

Comment: when calling malloc(), realloc(), 1) in C, do not cast the returned value from these functions.  the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   For realloc(), this means using a temporary variable, so if realloc() fails, the allocated memory pointer is not lost.  Losing the allocated memory pointer results in a memory leak.

Comment: regarding the calls to `scanf()`  always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful. (in the current scenario, any returned value except 1 indicates an error occurred.   Regarding this line: `scanf("%s", &(students[count].name));`   the '%s' format specifier will not step over `white space` (typically space, tab, newline) so the related scanf() will fail.   Suggest replacing the format string with: `" %s"`  (notice the leading space, which will consume any left over white space)

Comment: when calling `scanf()` with the '%s' format specifier, always limit the number of entered characters to 1 less than the length of the input buffer.  1) this allows for scanf() always appending a NUL char 2) this stops the user from entering enough characters to overflow the input buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: to allow for a student name to be more than one word, suggest using a format string of `" 24%[\n]:` so all characters will be input until a newline is entered and leading white space will be skipped and no buffer overflow will occur.